# Xcode Navigation Bar Goes under ScrollView?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview

Design mode everything is fine but in live Navigation Bar goes under the ScrollView How am I gonna solve this problem ? Please help

[image: Navigation Bar goes under scrollview]

Comment: Is the navigationBar created by a UINavigationController that the ViewController is embedded in, or are you manually adding the navigationBar?

Comment: @dzk  No UINavigationController

Comment: If you could provide some code of what you're doing with regards to the UINavigationBar and UIScrollView, it would be helpful.

Comment: @dzk There is no code :) 

But. Live scren is self.presentViewController

Comment: So where are you presenting the view from, and how are you presenting it?

Comment: webview controller delegate method I am checking url == some link and I am presenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, without seeing any code at all it is hard to say, but I believe that the navigationBar isn't displaying at all. If you're presenting the `UIViewController` directly from another view, you're not instantiating the `UINavigationController` it is embedded in.

A solution would be to either create a segue in your storyboard from your presenting view to the `UINavigationController`, or add a storyboardId to the `UINavigationController` and instantiating as:

```
let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STORYBOARD_ID_HERE") as! UINavigationController
presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you can show some code on how the view is presented you'll receive better help, since it's impossible to know exactly what is wrong based on just one image.

Comment: I said There is no code 2 View Controller 1 of them contains web view and url == http://.... I Am presenting other view just it. As you can see design mode navigation exist and I am not hiding it. Scroll view blocking I dont know why :(

Comment: I really can't help you if you don't show me everything leading up to `self.presentViewController(...)`

Comment: in first View controller webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest method 
I am presenting the other viewcontroller like thislet storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            let vc:ArizaKayitViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ariza") as! ArizaKayitViewController;
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);

This is all code :)

Comment: thank you that codes work!!
let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STORYBOARD_ID_HERE") as! UINavigationController
presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
the problem is presenting. :) I think when I presenting view controller Actualy it presenting view controller Content! not controller. Thank you so much!